# IE10 504 Bad Gateway Error on AJAX Form Submission

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10

I'm suddenly getting a `504 Bad Gateway error` on an AJAX form submission in IE10.

Everything worked fine until this week (or at least, that's when we found the issue), so I'm assuming that a recent security patch broke something.

My dev site is at `http://dev.superiorcelebrations.com`, and the problem is when you try to checkout using PayPal as the payment method.

For some reason, IE10 breaks during the submission to PayPal's website, and at this point I can't figure out whether it's an AJAX/jQuery issue, or an HTTP request problem, or what!

But, it's only when submitting to PayPal, and it's only on IE10, and it's only started happening very recently.

The browser's console isn't throwing any relevant script errors, and I don't know enough about the Fiddler debugger to glean anything useful from that data.

*I know that I'm not providing much to go on, but frankly, I feel like I don't have much to go on*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my form's submit button did not have a `name` attribute. IE apparently submits the button's value in the POST data with the rest of the form inputs, so it was sending a string that ended with:

```
&=value
```

instead of:

```
&name=value
```

I hope this helps someone else.